# training operation not getting loaded after restoring model Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried this:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path)+".meta")

sess  = tf.Session()
if(tf.train.checkpoint_exists(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))):
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
    print(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path) + "Session Loaded for Testing")     
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
X = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y)) # loss function = mean squared error
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss))
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Duplicate node name in graph: 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/layer0/kernel/Adam'
```

I tried using the name as mentioned in the error:

```
optimizer = graph.get_operation_by_name("rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/layer0/kernel/Adam")
```

Then I received this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute 'minimize'
```

Please let me know how I can get access to the `training_op` from the model?

Comment: Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: What is the output of `tf.train.list_variables(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))` ?
And if you insert `print(tf.global_variables())` right after get default graph line ?

Comment: Here is the answer to you question:  https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/d5721162647ecf725fd297501b050028

Comment: It's strange, everything looks ok. I can't reproduce error. How  `outputs` is defined?

Comment: I am trying to use the model from here: https://www.kaggle.com/raoulma/ny-stock-price-prediction-rnn-lstm-gru/notebook, you will get the outputs and rest other variables.

Comment: Try using any optimizer, which name doesn't start with Ada. The use adaptive algorithm that adds variables to each layer. Try SDG.

Comment: I understand that. But I want to use Adam optimizer. It is good for my training and even prediction.

Comment: It's understood. I proposed using SDG just to localize problem. Also try `  train_op = tf.get_collection('train_op')` It's from docs https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph

Comment: @Sharky Thank you for the help. I will try it out.